# SQL query to order by a special condition

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a table A as below :-

```
id parent_id
1    null
2    1
3    null
4    1
5    3
6    1
7    null
8    7
9    777
```

I want to write a query that returns the order as below :-

```
id parent_id
9    777
1    null
2    1
4    1
6    1
3    null
5    3  
7    null
8    7
```

If a row has a parent_id which is not in table A, it goes first.
Then all id's with null parent_id's are second, and if there's an id referencing to another id or the parent_id is not null to be precise, they are ordered just below the parent_id row.

How would I do this in postgresql ? 
This is what I have come up with so far and wanted a second pair of eyes and possible improvements.
Case 1 is when a row has a parent_id but the parent_id is not in table A, it takes highest priority.
Case 2 is when a row doesn't have a parent_id then it's priority 2.
Case 3 is when a row has a parent_id then it's priority 3.

What's happening is that, CASE 2 lists all the docs that matches CASE 2 and then lists all docs that matches CASE 3 which I don't want.

```sql
select id, parent_id from A 
order by 
case 
  when parent_id is not null and parent_id not in ( select id from A) then 1
  when parent_id is null then 2 
  when parent_id is not null and parent_id in ( select id from A) then 3 
  else parent_id END asc limit 100;
```

How would I do this in sqlalchemy ? Haven't given this a thought yet. But once I crack the sql query, converting it into sqlalchemy would be straightforward afaik.

I could easily process the sqlalchemy object and order them using some for loops and if else conditions but I wanted to learn how to do this on the sql querying level.

BONUS : I want to sort them via a date say created at. After above logic gives me the correct order, apply another ordering that orders via created at, maintaining the first order.

Would love some feedback. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample data has parents only one level deep, so you can do:

```
select t.*
from t left join
     t tp
     on t.id = t.parent_id
order by ( tp.id is null and t.parent_id is not null) desc,
         coalesce(parent_id, id),
         ( t.parent_id is null ) desc,
         t.id  -- the final sorting criterion
```

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jWN47PcixGH9n66qKshXX8/0) is a db fiddle.

Comment: coalesce(parent_id, id) should be coalesce(t.parent_id, tp.id) ? And what do you mean by parent only one level deep.

Comment: @skyfail . . . You data has no "grandparents" in it.

Comment: Hey, I created a sql fiddle here -> https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=tsgbc2uum7 .  Your above query doesn't seem to give me the desired output.

Comment: Seems to be working after your modifications but what if I want to also order by created_at ? It messes up the output if the dates are same for parent and child row.

Comment: @skyfail . . . replace the last key -- `t.id` -- with the column you want to sort the children by.

Comment: Thanks a ton Gordon !!